# LDO voltage regulator, no output

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, ldo

I'm making my own board based on Arduino. To power it I use one LIR2032 cell (button cell 3.6V li-ion battery) that's driven through 3.3V LDO voltage regulator. So far I have tried two different regulators:

- MIC5504-3.3YM5-TR
- LD59015C33R

and none of them worked, both did not give any voltage at the output.
So far I have tried:

- connecting ENABLE pin to VIN (in the second one could be left floating, PCB has an error design  with EN disconnected but I've already corrected it!)
- replacing part (in case of ESD)
- correcting joints (in case of cold joints, multimeter shows proper connection)

The voltage regulator is wired the same way as shown in the datasheet

[image: BP+ is battery input].

The board works when powered via other source of power so it's not the case of it just not working. Trying different batteries and higher voltages did not solve the problem, output still shows 0V.
I have no idea what could be wrong, I hope you can help me with that!

If you have any other regulators to recommend please comment, board needs no more than 100mA.
[image]
[image]

(Yes component is bigger than the pads :) MIC5504 is slightly larger than LD59015 but I managed to solder it properly)

Comment: Have you measured the load current?  Is it withing specs?  Even on startup?

Comment: The battery negative terminal is connected to the same ground, right? Did you measure the battery voltage when is it connected?

Comment: Yes, battery is connected to ground.

Comment: According to datasheet MIC5504 does not need any load. I've tried adding an LED to use some power but it seems to not work.

Comment: Why does the GND pad of C16 in your PCB layout have an unconnected net "air wire" leading off somewhere? Are you sure that GND of the regulator really is connected to GND of your battery?

Comment: Looks like there is another air-wire under U5 too.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point! I was pretty sure I've checked if all grounds are connected. I don't know from where this air wire came from so I ignored it (I must have moved one part so that GND "island" formed or via deleted itself right before sending it to production). I need to check that again, this could be it! Thank you very much :D

Comment: No... That's not the problem, all GNDs are connected :(

Comment: So if you measure with a multimeter directly across pins1-2 rights at the LDO, you do measure battery voltage?

Comment: Yes, battery voltage is there. That's the reason I created this post. It's very confusing, I can't believe that 3 of the regulators got fried

Comment: Suggest you fire up your PCB layout program with the exact design you sent out, and do a design rule check. Make sure you understand every single error it lists (if any). There are two rubber band connections apparently not routed and maybe there's other things too.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. My temporary connection to ENABLE didn't work but when I soldered it regulator started to work flawlessly. As I said MIC5504 does not need EN pin connected (that's written in the datasheet) but that happened to be false! It has to!

Comment: @Poij - The datasheet was not technically incorrect; it does say that for the MIC5504 it is ok to float the pin, but if you read carefully it implies that it will be disabled when using the internal pull down. They just mean that it is safe to float the pin and won't cause any damage to the part. For the MIC5501 and 2 it is not OK to float the pin at all, whether you want it to be off or on. It is very confusing though and a strange design decision (they should made EN active low, not active high, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pad 3 is not connected to BP+, unlike shown in the schematic. This means EN is disconnected and the LDO won't power up.

I am not certain that the schematic shows a *proper* connection to the pin, as there is a 90° angle. This may confuse the software enough to *not* make a connection here.

Comment: That's true, but it's still not working when connected. MIC5504 even does not need this connection.

Comment: I want to apologize to everyone who I said that EN has to be connected :D I soldered this connection and happened to work!
Lesson learned: DO NOT TRUST DATASHEETS! :)